# Baby Rudin — Theorem 1.21 inequality

Tags: real-analysis

Quoting Principles of Mathematical Analysis (3rd Ed.) by Walter Rudin, page 10:

> **1.21 Theorem**. *For every real $x > 0$ and every integer $n > 0$ there is one and only one positive real $y$ such that $y^n = x$.*

> **Proof.** That there is at most one such $y$ is clear, since $0 < y_1 < y_2$ implies $y_1^n < y_2^n$. Let $E$ be the the set containing all positive real numbers $t$ such that $t^n < x$. If $t = x/(1 + x)$ then $0 \leq t < 1$. Hence $t^n \leq t < x$. Thus $t \in E$, and $E$ is not empty. $\quad$ [rest of proof ommitted]

I don't know where the $\leq$ sign comes from, given that $x > 0$ and $t$ is positive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\le$ includes the possibility $<$, so there is nothing incorrect in what is written, but it could be made more precise by putting $<$, as you noted.

Using $\le$ versus $<$ is often a matter of preference since they are frequently equivalent. Consider the usual $\varepsilon$, $\delta$ definition of limits:

$f(x)\to L$ as $x\to a$ if for each $\varepsilon > 0$, there is some $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$ whenever is $x$ is chosen so that $0<|x-a|<\delta$.

An equivalent definition is achieved if we use $\le$:

$f(x)\to L$ as $x\to a$ if for each $\varepsilon > 0$, there is some $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x)-L|\le \varepsilon$ whenever is $x$ is chosen so that $0<|x-a|<\delta$.

It may be a good exercise to prove the two definitions given above are equivalent.

Comment: Is there an advantage using $\leq$ over $<$? Or is it simply "neater" to include $0$?

Comment: I think that using $\le$ over $<$ has the advantage that it includes more cases, because it is a weaker condition. Said differently, there is the potential to assert an incorrect statement if you use $<$, so it is a little bit "safer" to use $\le$. I added more to my answer on this.